# What is the mysterious stranger doing in my vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

This morning after the new Fallout Shelter update (1.2), I saw a mysterious stranger hiding in one of my rooms. When he is tapped  there is a sound cue and he disappears in a puff of black vapor.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I just read the update notes and it mentioned something about a mysterious occurrence and there was a cap reward for information on it....perhaps if you find him a certain amount of times you will get rewarded?

Comment: [This bethesda forum thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1539130-finally-fos-12-update/) mention a character that gives cap when clicked on. Sounds like a new way to earn caps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clicking on him gives you caps.

I got 2460 caps the last time. Others report up to 5000 caps.

Listen for a piano sound. You have a few seconds to find him and get the caps.

He disappears after a second sound is played.

He was added in [version 1.2](https://youtu.be/kizzTSyvoLQ)

Comment: I have gotten between 100 and 5k caps before. Also, if you have sound off, phone will vibrate twice when he appears, once when he disappears. I didn't start to get 5k caps until recently with 200 dwellers, and some of them with maxed out luck.

Answer (score 2):

The mysterious stranger will give you 250 caps if you can tap him before he disappears. He does not appear to take part in combat.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to other answers.

The important thing about the piano sound is that it is coming from Stranger's location and when playing with headphones and zoomed in at the moment, it is not so difficult to determine the direction and the distance, especially after getting used to it.

Answer (score 1):

The mysterious stranger is a reference to the perk from Fallout 3. Saw him also first time I played after update. Wish he would have hung around little longer though - barely noticed him. Hopefully he shows up next time those f'ng deathclaws do..

Comment: Great perk too: just when you forget you took the perk, he shows up and laughter ensues. I always wished there was a film-noir audio track to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

He gives cap rewards, but is the amount of caps based on level or is it how long you take to tap him, or maybe even the room he's in at that moment, or EVEN if your I combat or not... So many questions (also what triggers him to enter your vault)

Comment: The question was already answered with the same answer.