# Dweller from the Future?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have the new updated version of Fallout Shelter... and as I went back onto the game to collect the production and stuff. I saw this weird guy with a detective-like coat in my Weight Room. I zoomed in and then he dissapeared. Glitch maybe?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand this situation. Are you asking us if it *was* a glitch, or is this a long-standing issue?

Comment: I'm asking if this is a glitch

Comment: Do you have any possible screenshot? Could you at least describe this character in greater detail?

Comment: Even this guy saw it! Look in the newest questions and scroll down until you see something with 1K Views saying he saw the same thing

Comment: Uhm. *Who* saw it? Can you provide a link to this question? Because if that's the case, if that question's been answered, your question could be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239793/what-is-the-mysterious-stranger-doing-in-my-vault

Comment: Seeing as that's already been asked, in that case, this question may well be a duplicate. However, I wouldn't bet that it *is* a duplicate yet, there might be a more detailed answer for this.

Comment: @Texenox that a answer on this question is more detailed doesn't change the fact that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau On second thought, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Mysterious Stranger from the new patch. If you click him in time he gives you bonus caps, I've gotten ranges from 43 to 250 caps so far. You can find the patch notes [here](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/new-fallout-4-character-added-in-fallout-shelter-u/1100-6431458/). He doesn't seem to have a set frequency yet to show up, and it seems to vary from three to ten seconds (or it's more regular and that's how long it's taking me to notice him).

Comment: I got over 2.3k caps from him.  It raised my caps from 999,999 to... 999,999.