# I saw a ghost on fallout shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was just taking care of my vault and out of the corner of my eye it looked like someone was standing in the back of the storage room once I saw him he disappeared and then this weird music started to play like dun dun daaaaaa I waited for awhile and I herd that music again but I didn't see it in time. Who is this figure?

Answer (score -1):

I think this may what you're looking for:

[What is the mysterious stranger doing in my vault?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239793/what-is-the-mysterious-stranger-doing-in-my-vault)

The question here doesn't mention any ghost-like features, but you seem to both  mention a sound cue, which is also mentioned in that question.

EDIT:
I just realized that Lex asked about this under your post, but I hope this helped :P

Comment: While you are correct, it is for the same reason that this question will likely be closed as a duplicate. For questions that are duplicates, it is best not to post another answer, as this just makes clean up more troublesome.